# Declare Multiple DB Host in an array and make DB calls

Tags: php, mysql, database, scripting, mysqli

I'm new to PHP. What I'm trying to achieve is declare multiple DB hosts in an array. Something like below mentioned :

```
  $slaves=array(
        array(  //Slave 1
                'name' => 'slave1',
                'server' => '10.10.1.10',
                'user' => 'user1',
                'password' => 'p@ssuser1'
                'port' => '3306'),
        array(  //Slave 2
                'name' => 'slave2',
                'server' => '10.10.1.11',
                'user' => 'user2',
                'password' => 'p@ssuser2'
                'port' => '3306'),
        )
```

Once done, I want to make random calls to these slaves i.e., every read request should get served from one of the slaves.

```
  $idx = time() % count($slaves);
$slave = $slaves[$idx];
$con = mysqli_connect($slave['server'], $slave['user'], $slave['password'], "dbname");
```

But this is not working. If I try to connect these slaves individually, it is working. But not when I declare that in an array. Is there a simple way to make random calls to these slaves ? Please highlight where is the mistake in my code. I have checked few links on web but they use functions and this keyword to make DB calls.

If you require any more information, do let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't call time()-based choice a random one. If I am not mistaken, all your scripts will connect to the same server at a time

Comment: Not working means I was getting a blank screen. Figured out there was a syntax error too. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$slave = $slaves[array_rand($slaves)];
$con = mysqli_connect($slave['server'], $slave['user'], $slave['password'], "dbname");
```

Comment: Next time, please read manual before posting. `array_rand` returns random index, not value.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `array_rand` function to get random value from array. Check it with this modification.

And you forget to pass database name to connect function.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Using array_rand, its working. Database name was already provided manually "dbname".